# Центровка сайта

Tags: html, css

У меня есть вопрос по CSS: как можно центрировать сайт в середину экрана, так чтобы блоки были на одном расстоянии друг от друга на разных разрешениях экрана, т.к. у меня экран очень широкий, я пишу код как бы для одного разрешения экрана, а для других экранов идёт всё косо... Прошу написать подробное описание CSS кода с `<div>`.

Answer (score 5):

Весь контент оборачиваете в див:

```
<div id="center-content">
    <div>шапка</div>
    <div>меню/контент</div>
    <div>футер</div>
</div>
```

И потом в css:

```
#center-content{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;/* например, укажете нужную ширину */
}
```

Comment: Вроде бы всё так, но если нужно добавить блоки меню, а в дивной системе див отталкивается от дива (грубо говоря), как мне централизовать всю страницу? Я знаю, что есть команды для независимости тега. Но... могли бы вы  подробно написать код с шапкой блоком меню и футером, буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Не понимаю проблемы. Оборачиваете всю страницу в эту обертку и все, ну или только необходимую ее часть. Или вы дивы не можете расположить горизонтально?

Comment: Мне нужно написать код для статичного сайта, шапка меню, под ним блок с меню (левый) и футер, но так чтобы этот сайт имел общую ширину, например, 1000 пикселей, но на всех экранах выглядел как обычный сайт, а не блок меню дальше, чем нужно и т.д. Можете дать мне примерный код.

Comment: Вы наверное издеваетесь? Может я заработался, но я ВООБЩЕ не понимаю, в чем сложность? Оборачиваете весь свой сайт в обертку, предложенную мной, и всё будет по центру! Учим основы css!

Comment: Спасибо проехали ...

Comment: Научитесь грамотно задавать вопрос, а то сидишь и гадаешь на кофейной гуще, чего Вы хотите...

Comment: так бы и  написали нето обёртка обёртка я не понял а сказали бы заключить дивы в див тогда понятно было бы

Comment: Кхм, прочитайте первую строчку моего ответа)

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
Контент
</div>
```

C такими параметрами див всегда будет находиться по центру родителя.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="margin:0 auto;width:1000px;">

<div id="header" style="height:150px;">

<div id="left_col" style="float:left;width:200px;"></div>
<div id="content" style="float:left;width:auto;"></div>

<div id="footer" style="clear:both; height:150px;"></div>

</div>
```